# Flash polyline with different spatial reference from the displaying object(IScreenDisplay). Esri arc 9.3

Tags: c#, esri

I'm working on an application which uses Albers equal area projections, then I load a shape file with a different spatial reference, I cant get to flash the polyline on the GIS editor (GIS Map) I tried the code snippet I got from esri, but it aint helping. I'm assuming its because of the spatial reference objects are not the same in the geometry and the IScreenDisplay object. how can I solve this. Please help and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well guys I figured it out, I had to create a dynamic transparent layer with no styling on top of the map. each time I need to flash a geometry I draw that geometry on the dynamic layer in different styling for about a half a second then call the finish drawing method. to remove it from the layer.